# Splitting punctuation into a list (Python)

Tags: string, list, python-3.x

I want to be able to generate a list that includes the punctuation but I am struggling to find a solution.

Example: "Hello world! I am here."

```
["Hello","world","!","I","am","here","."]
```

So far I know that

```
"Hello World! I am here.".split()
```

will evaluate to

```
['Hello', 'World!', 'I', 'am', 'here.']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regex` :

```
>>> s="Hello world! I am here."
>>> 
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\w+|[^\w\s]',s)
['Hello', 'world', '!', 'I', 'am', 'here', '.']
```

`re.findall()` with Regex `r'\w+|[^\w\s]'` will find all combinations of word characters (`\w+`) or every thing except word character or white-spaces (`[^\w\s]`).

Comment: Thank you that works by itself but when I try this ` def collectText():
    text = input("Please type text")
    global textList
    textList=""
    textList = re.findall(r'\w+S',text)  collectText()
print(textList)`  I just get ` []`

Comment: @Amy You have passed a wrong regex to `findall` function you should pass `'\w+|[^\w\s]'`